# swift how to set dynamic height when having multiple custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

How do I set the height based on content, having multiple custom UITableViewCell ?

This is how I've tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
var currentCell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
println("reuseIdentifier: \(currentCell?.reuseIdentifier)")

currentCell?.layoutIfNeeded()

let height: CGFloat = currentCell?.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height as CGFloat!
let separatorHeight:CGFloat = 1

return height + separatorHeight
}
```

but it crashes since I cannot get the current cell.

Comment: it crashes because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` actually calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you are creating a loop. Why are you doing it?

Comment: @JuniorB.: I know that it crashes. Actually I want to get the reuseIdentifier of the cell and set the height of the cell based on content

Comment: Are you supporting iOS 8 only?

Comment: @Isuru: nope, iOS 7+ . I know that iOS 8 has Dynamic UITableViewCell

Comment: @el.severo Have you come across [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)? It shows how to calculate the cell height when you have multiple cell types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cellForRowAt set tableview accessibilityHint

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  tableview.accessibilityHint = NUMBERINPUT

  self.tableview.register(textFieldNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
  TEXT_FIELD_CELL_IDENTIFIER)

  let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
  TEXT_FIELD_CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: index)as! TextFieldTableViewCell

  return cell

 }
```

In heightForRowAt check accessibilityHint and adjust the height of custom UITableViewCell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if tableView.accessibilityHint == NUMBERINPUT{

        return 500

    }else{

        return 100

    }

}
```